# using python for coping highlighted text in another program

Tags: python, windows, automation

I have a python script that has a key-shortcut for running. I want to be able to select text with the mouse, and to use it as an input for my python script. At the end of the script I want to paste the output of the script instead of the text that was marked. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should put your incomplete code here. That would be a great help for people trying to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.